Azure DevOps Pipeline fails to deploy Azure Static Web App with self-hosted Windows agent
I am trying to deploy my first Azure Static Web App from Azure DevOps using a self-hosted agent on my local Windows machine. The agent is set up and appears online in the Azure DevOps settings. However, I am encountering an issue with the AzureStaticWebApp task in my pipeline.
Here is the YAML configuration of the pipeline:
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master

jobs:
- job: build_and_deploy_job
  displayName: Build and Deploy Job
  condition: or(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual'),or(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'),eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI')))
  pool:
    name: Local Agent Pool
  variables:
  - group: Azure-Static-Web-Apps-victorious-beach-0d42cb803-variable-group
  steps:
  - checkout: self
    submodules: true
  - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
    inputs:
      azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_VICTORIOUS_BEACH_0D42CB803)
      app_location: "/"
      api_location: ""
      output_location: "build"
      skip_api_build: true

Now the issue: When I run the pipeline, the AzureStaticWebApp task fails with the following error message:
2024-10-04T14:42:16.5040695Z [command]C:\WINDOWS\system32\bash.exe C:\agent\_work\_tasks\AzureStaticWebApp_18aad896-e191-4720-88d6-8ced4806941a\0.246.1\launch-docker.sh
2024-10-04T14:42:22.3067301Z /bin/bash: C:agent_work_tasksAzureStaticWebApp_18aad896-e191-4720-88d6-8ced4806941a0.246.1launch-docker.sh: No such file or directory
2024-10-04T14:42:22.3142262Z 
2024-10-04T14:42:22.3238448Z ##[error]Error: The process 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\bash.exe' failed with exit code 127
2024-10-04T14:42:22.3285032Z ##[section]Finishing: AzureStaticWebApp

I think the problem appears to be related to how paths are being handled. The command that fails seems to use a Windows-style path, but the Bash environment expects a Linux-style path. I believe it should look something like this:
C:\WINDOWS\system32\bash.exe mnt\c\agent\_work\_tasks\AzureStaticWebApp_18aad896-e191-4720-88d6-8ced4806941a\0.246.1\launch-docker.sh

But I have no idea to change it, nor any idea if I should change it somewhere or if my configuration is incorrect... Any help?
WSL is correctly installed and docker is also accessible within the WSL environment.

The AzureStaticWebApp@0 task can only run on Linux agents. It is not available for Windows agents.

To run this task, you can:

Use the Microsoft-hosted agents which is on Linux VM, such as ubuntu-24.04, ubuntu-22.04 (ubuntu-latest) or ubuntu-20.04.

Install self-hosted agents on yourself local Linux machines or Linux VM.




As clarified in the answer, you need to used Linux agents to run the AzureStaticWebApp@0 task. Have tried as this, and does it work for you? @EmileCaron

The correct answer is already given by Bright Ran-MSFT. I only want to say that you can use a workaround if you don't want to make use of an Linux agent.
You can also make use of a storage account for static websites. I am not sure if that will fit your needs, but if it does, than you might consider to use the option below.
How I deploy a static website is:
I am using an ARM template for a storage account.
    - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  displayName: "Create Static Website Storage Account"
  inputs:
    deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
    azureResourceManagerConnection: ${{ parameters['ServiceConnection']}}
    subscriptionId: $(SubscriptionID)
    action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
    resourceGroupName: $(ResourceGroup)
    location: 'West Europe'
    templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
    csmFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/armtemplates/staticwebapp_deployment.json'
    csmParametersFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/armtemplates/staticwebapp_parameters.json'
    deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
    overrideParameters: '-SubscriptionName $(subname) -VersionToDeploy $(VersionToDeploy) -StorageAccountNameStaticWebApp $(StaticWebAppName)'
  continueOnError: false

The second task is a AzurePowershell task which I use to enable static website.
    - task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: "Enable Static Website"
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters['ServiceConnection']}}
    ScriptType: 'FilePath'
    ScriptPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/Scripts/EnableStaticWebSite.ps1'
    ScriptArguments: '-ResourceGroup $(ResourceGroup) -StorageAccountNameStaticWebApp $(StorageAccountNameStaticWebApp)'
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
  continueOnError: false

Maybe this will help you to deploy it as an workaround. I have not included the arm template and the script itself, but if you need I can paste it here.
